# How do align the prices to be parallel with the items on my mock restuarant menu

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align the items on the menu down one side of it and the prices down the other side of the menu. I have gotten the items to line up into one single column, but the prices do not line up, they are all displayed differently depending on how long the item is.

I tried messing with the inline block, the padding, and width but they all just throw the whole page off. Or they items just go to opposite edges of the page with no space inbtween the word and the edge of the page.
Im not really sure what to do.  Also sorry if my question is confusing, i am very new at this.

````
.menu-page {
  background-color: white;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 15px auto;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.food {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.meat, .price {
  display: inline;
}

.meat {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.price {
  margin-left: 55%;
}

.toppings {
  text-align: center;
}

.description {
  font-style: italic;
  color: darkgray;
  font-size: 11px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

<body>
  <div class="menu-page">
    <h1>Zackie's Tacos</h1>
    <p class="catchphrase">Award winning tacos!</p>
    <hr>
    <div class="food">
      <h2>Tacos</h2>
        <h5 class="meat">Chicken</h5> 
        <p class="price">2.50<p>
        <h5 class="meat">Beef</h5>
        <p class="price">2.75<p>
        <h5 class="meat">Carne Asada</h5>
        <p class="price">3.15<p></p>
        <h5 class="meat">Carnitas</h5>
        <p class="price">3.15<p></p>
        <h5 class="meat">Barbacoa</h5>
        <p class="price">3.15<p></p>
        <h5 class="meat">Shrimp</h5>
        <p class="price">3.50<p></p>
        <h5 class="meat">Fish</h5>
        <p class="price">3.50<p></p>
      <h4 class="toppings">Toppings</h4>
        <p class="description">lettuce, tomato, cilantro, onion, raddish, jalapeno, black or pinto bean, cheese, sour cream, any signature sauce.</p>```
````

Comment: Go through https://codepen.io/1wdtv/pen/avKEOo  and change your markup accordingly .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Use Flexbox

Here is a solution that uses [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox).

You can wrap each item into a `div` tag that has `display: flex`.
This will bring both your `h5` and `p` element into the same line.

To shift both the items into respective ends, you can provide `justify-content: space-between` to the div(.item) element.

Note: Be aware that `h5` and `p` elements has its own margin by default. Hence, I have reassigned the margin as `margin: 1rem 0;` to .meat and .price.

````html
<style>
.menu-page {
  background-color: white;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 15px auto;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.food {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.meat {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.meat, .price {
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.toppings {
  text-align: center;
}

.description {
  font-style: italic;
  color: darkgray;
  font-size: 11px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

</style>
<body>
  <div class="menu-page">
    <h1>Zackie's Tacos</h1>
    <p class="catchphrase">Award winning tacos!</p>
    <hr>
    <div class="food">
      <h2>Tacos</h2>
      <div class="item"><h5 class="meat">Chicken</h5> <p class="price">2.50</p></div>
      <div class="item"><h5 class="meat">Beef</h5><p class="price">2.75</p></div>
      <div class="item"><h5 class="meat">Carne Asada</h5><p class="price">3.15</p></div>
      <div class="item"><h5 class="meat">Carnitas</h5><p class="price">3.15</p></div>
      <div class="item"><h5 class="meat">Barbacoa</h5><p class="price">3.15</p></div>
      <div class="item"><h5 class="meat">Shrimp</h5><p class="price">3.50</p></div>
      <div class="item"><h5 class="meat">Fish</h5><p class="price">3.50</p></div>
      <h4 class="toppings">Toppings</h4>
        <p class="description">lettuce, tomato, cilantro, onion, raddish, jalapeno, black or pinto bean, cheese, sour cream, any signature sauce.</p>```
````

Answer (score 1):

The `inline` CSS property defines the horizontal or vertical **size** of an element's block, depending on its writing mode, so when you `margin-left` on `price` class It will not align all `p` tag vertically.

You can use `flexbox` or `grid` to divide it into 2 cols i.e:

```html
<p class="grid grid-cols-2">
   <span>Chicken</span>
   <span>2.50</span>
</p>

.grid {
  display: grid;
}

.grid-cols-2 {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
}
```